# How to pass float pointer to function which takes double pointer

Tags: c, pointers, casting

I have a function which takes in a pointer to a double
and does some stuff to it. Suppose I have a pointer to a float
which was created via malloc or calloc. How would I pass this pointer to the function
correctly? I tried simply casting via (double *)var, but that doesn't do what I'd expect.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void TestFunc(double *x, long arr_size)
{
    long i;
    for (i=0; i<arr_size; ++i)
        x[i] = (double)i;
}


int main()
{
    long i;
    long n = 10;
    float *x = (float *)calloc(sizeof(float), n);

    TestFunc((double *)x, n);

    for (i=0; i<n; ++i)
        printf("%f\n", x[i]);

    return 0;
}
```

I also tried using pointer arithmetic instead of indexing:

```
void TestFunc(double *x, long arr_size, size_t size)
{
    long i;
    for (i=0; i<arr_size; ++i)
    {
        *x = (double)i;
        x += size;
    }
    x -= size*arr_size;
}

int main()
{
    long i;
    long n = 10;
    float *x = (float *)calloc(sizeof(float), n);

    TestFunc((double *)x, n, sizeof(float *));

    for (i=0; i<n; ++i)
        printf("%f\n", x[i]);

    return 0;
}
```

The outcome for the first method is:

```
0.000000
0.000000
0.000000
1.875000
0.000000
2.000000
0.000000
2.125000
0.000000
2.250000
```

and the output for the second is all zeros, whereas I'd expect 0.0, ..., 9.0. Any suggestions?

EDIT: The goal is to make the following code much shorter. It's for a Python extension and I want to safely handle various data types.

```
if (typenum == NPY_FLOAT)
    _array_from_one(data, y, dim, float, CName##_Float);
else if (typenum == NPY_DOUBLE)
    _array_from_one(data, y, dim, double, CName##_Double);
else if (typenum == NPY_LONGDOUBLE)
    _array_from_one(data, y, dim, long double, CName##_Long_Double);
else
{
    if (typenum == NPY_BYTE)
        _array_to_double(data, y, dim, char, CName##_Double);
    else if (typenum == NPY_UBYTE)
        _array_to_double(data, y, dim, unsigned char, CName##_Double);
    else if (typenum == NPY_SHORT)
        _array_to_double(data, y, dim, short, CName##_Double);
    else if (typenum == NPY_USHORT)
        _array_to_double(data, y, dim, unsigned short, CName##_Double);
    else if (typenum == NPY_INT)
        _array_to_double(data, y, dim, int, CName##_Double);
    else if (typenum == NPY_UINT)
        _array_to_double(data, y, dim, unsigned int, CName##_Double);
    else if (typenum == NPY_LONG)
        _array_to_double(data, y, dim, long, CName##_Double);
    else if (typenum == NPY_ULONG)
        _array_to_double(data, y, dim, unsigned long, CName##_Double);
    else if (typenum == NPY_LONGLONG)
        _array_to_double(data, y, dim, long long, CName##_Double);
    else if (typenum == NPY_ULONGLONG)
        _array_to_double(data, y, dim, unsigned long long, CName##_Double);
    else {
        PyErr_Format(PyExc_TypeError,
                    "Invalid data type.",
                    VarToString(FuncName));
        return NULL;
    }
    typenum = NPY_DOUBLE;
}
```

The two macros are defined by:

```
#define _array_from_one(x, y, dim, type, f) ({                                 \
    long i;                                                                    \
    type *out = (type *)malloc(sizeof(type)*dim);                              \
    for (i=0; i<dim; ++i) out[i] = (*f)(((type *)x)[i]);                       \
    y = out;                                                                   \
})

#define _array_to_double(x, y, dim, type, f) ({                                \
    long i;                                                                    \
    double *out = (double *)malloc(sizeof(double)*dim);                        \
    for (i=0; i<dim; ++i)                                                      \
        out[i] = (*f)((double)((type *)x)[i]);                                 \
    y = out;                                                                   \
})
```

This works and allows me to safely pass float, double, and long double numpy arrays while preserving the precision, and covert all integer types to double and process them, however it's ugly. The code at the start of this question was meant to shorten and clean this up. Any suggestions welcome!

Comment: You cannot do that because `float` is not `double`.

Comment: Yes, I understand this, and my current solution is to have separate functions. However, the actual code is for a Python package where I safely want to handle numpy arrays of a plethora of types (char, int, short, long, long long, float, double, long double, and their unsigned counterparts). Having 13 aliases per function means quite a lot of functions!

Answer (score 1):

> How to pass float pointer to function which takes double pointer

If changing the test function is not an option as well as the type of `x`, assign the `float` elements to a `double` array, call the test function, and assign again.

```
double tmp[n];  // VLA or the usual malloc/free
for (i=0; i<n; i++) tmp[i] = x[i];
TestFunc(tmp, n);
for (i=0; i<n; i++) x[i] = tmp[i];
```

Comment: Welp, I'm an idiot, that is a very simple solution. Thanks! There's no legal way to type cast an array or pointer in this way, however?

Comment: @RyanMaguire There are complaint ways to perform pointer casts, yet code will not achieve the needed functionality via casts alone.  Each array element needs to convert between FP types.

Comment: @RyanMaguire You need a valid `double*` value, which means it needs to point to a valid object of type `double` in memory. If you have an array of `float`, there are no `double` objects in memory to point to. You'll need to create an array of `double` objects in memory. No way around that (unless you can change the type expected by the function or the type of the existing array, neither of which appears to be possible).

Answer (score 0):

I guess in your first code, you allocate memory for float type. Then you change variable type of x to double, which takes more memory than float. Try also recall function as a variable then print it out.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand that final bit "Try also recall function as a variable then print it out." Can you explain?

Comment: forget this part below posted new answer, which I solved by myself

Answer (score 0):

solved! change double to float like that 'void TestFunc(float *x, long arr_size)'
and in your main function TestFunc(x, n); should be like that

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void TestFunc(float *x, long arr_size)
{
    long i;
    for (i=0; i<arr_size; ++i)
        x[i] = (float)i;
}

int main()
{
    long i;
    long n = 10;
    float *x = (float *)calloc(sizeof(float), n);

    TestFunc(x, n);

    for (i = 0; i < n; ++i)
        printf("%f\n", x[i]);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Sorry, the point of the question is how to safely pass a pointer of type A to a function which wants type B. That's why TestFunc takes a double and I want to pass it a float. Sorry about that!